# Get brief human-readable info about XRI OpenID with Python?

Tags: python, openid, janrain, xri

I'd like to be able to tell to the site visitor that comes with his/her OpenID: **you are using your XYZ id for the first time on mysite - please create your sceen name**, where XYZ is a nice token that makes sense. For example - XYZ could be the provider name.

I'd like to find a solution that works for OpenID as defined in the standard - i.e. work for **XRI** type of ID - extensible resource identifier.

urlparse (as suggested by RichieHindle) works for url-type openid, but does not work in general, e.g. for **i-name** IDs like "=somename". There are many other forms of valid OpenID string that don't even closely look like url.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Since OpenIDs are URLs, this might be the cleanest way in the absence of built-in support in Janrain:

```
from urlparse import urlparse
openid_str = "http://myprovider/myname" # str(openid_obj)
parts = urlparse(openid_str)
provider_name = parts[1]
print (provider_name)  # Prints myprovider
```

Comment: thanks looks good but does not work with 
 xri://myprovider/myname
according to OpenID spec string might be xri too

Comment: Since you don't need the scheme (http, xri, etc) you could just strip it and urlparse will still work fine: openid_str = re.sub(r'^\w+:', '', openid_str)